# Portainer: Use environment from docker-compose

Tags: docker, portainer, teslamate

I have the following docker-compose.yml.

```
version: "3"

services:
  teslamate:
    image: teslamate/teslamate:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ENCRYPTION_KEY=asdf_key
      - DATABASE_USER=asdf_user
      - DATABASE_PASS=asdf_pass
      - DATABASE_NAME=asdf_name
      - DATABASE_HOST=asdf_host
      - MQTT_HOST=mosquitto
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    volumes:
      - ./import:/opt/app/import
    cap_drop:
      - all

  database:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=asdf_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=asdf_pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=asdf_db
    volumes:
      - teslamate-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  grafana:
    image: teslamate/grafana:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DATABASE_USER=asdf_user
      - DATABASE_PASS=asdf_pass
      - DATABASE_NAME=asdf_name
      - DATABASE_HOST=asdf_host
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - teslamate-grafana-data:/var/lib/grafana

environment:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:2
    restart: always
    command: mosquitto -c /mosquitto-no-auth.conf
    # ports:
    #   - 1883:1883
    volumes:
      - mosquitto-conf:/mosquitto/config
      - mosquitto-data:/mosquitto/data

  teslamateapi:
    image: tobiasehlert/teslamateapi:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      - ENCRYPTION_KEY=asdf_key
      - DATABASE_USER=asdf_user
      - DATABASE_PASS=asdf_pass
      - DATABASE_NAME=asdf_name
      - DATABASE_HOST=asdf_host
      - MQTT_HOST=mosquitto
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  teslamateagile:
    image: mattjeanes/teslamateagile:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DATABASE_USER=asdf_user
      - DATABASE_PASS=asdf_pass
      - DATABASE_NAME=asdf_name
      - DATABASE_HOST=asdf_host
      - TeslaMate__UpdateIntervalSeconds=300
      - TeslaMate__GeofenceId=1
      - TeslaMate__EnergyProvider=FixedPrice
      - FixedPrice__TimeZone=Europe/Berlin
      - FixedPrice__Prices__0=00:00-24:00=0.23

volumes:
  teslamate-db:
  teslamate-grafana-data:
  mosquitto-conf:
  mosquitto-data:
```

I want to use Portainer and add the compose file as a Stack but I get the error that
I can not use an additional environment.

What environment do I have to remove exactly? The variables from each service or

```
environment:
      mosquitto:
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to remove the line with environments.

```
version: "3"

services:
  teslamate:
    image: teslamate/teslamate:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ENCRYPTION_KEY=asdf_key
      - DATABASE_USER=asdf_user
      - DATABASE_PASS=asdf_pass
      - DATABASE_NAME=asdf_name
      - DATABASE_HOST=asdf_host
      - MQTT_HOST=mosquitto
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    volumes:
      - ./import:/opt/app/import
    cap_drop:
      - all

  database:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=asdf_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=asdf_pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=asdf_db
    volumes:
      - teslamate-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  grafana:
    image: teslamate/grafana:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DATABASE_USER=asdf_user
      - DATABASE_PASS=asdf_pass
      - DATABASE_NAME=asdf_name
      - DATABASE_HOST=asdf_host
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - teslamate-grafana-data:/var/lib/grafana

  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:2
    restart: always
    command: mosquitto -c /mosquitto-no-auth.conf
    # ports:
    #   - 1883:1883
    volumes:
      - mosquitto-conf:/mosquitto/config
      - mosquitto-data:/mosquitto/data

  teslamateapi:
    image: tobiasehlert/teslamateapi:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      - ENCRYPTION_KEY=asdf_key
      - DATABASE_USER=asdf_user
      - DATABASE_PASS=asdf_pass
      - DATABASE_NAME=asdf_name
      - DATABASE_HOST=asdf_host
      - MQTT_HOST=mosquitto
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  teslamateagile:
    image: mattjeanes/teslamateagile:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - DATABASE_USER=asdf_user
      - DATABASE_PASS=asdf_pass
      - DATABASE_NAME=asdf_name
      - DATABASE_HOST=asdf_host
      - TeslaMate__UpdateIntervalSeconds=300
      - TeslaMate__GeofenceId=1
      - TeslaMate__EnergyProvider=FixedPrice
      - FixedPrice__TimeZone=Europe/Berlin
      - FixedPrice__Prices__0=00:00-24:00=0.23

volumes:
  teslamate-db:
  teslamate-grafana-data:
  mosquitto-conf:
  mosquitto-data:
```

Similar to [the official Teslamate guide](https://docs.teslamate.org/docs/installation/docker)

`environment:` is used to declare variables for the specific container, so it has to be underneath the container.